# Sometimes "Ignored Tags" are not ignored in the active tab

Tags: bug, new-nav

I'm trying out the new navigation (loving it) but sometimes my active tab includes questions that should be hidden, since they contain a tag that's in my "ignored tags":

[image]

I'm using Safari 9.0.1 in OS X 10.11 - unfortunately I don't see a pattern where I could reproduce the bug and add details, it just happens sometimes.

---

There's something fishy about the `parse.com` tag specifically in my case, because I almost only see this one Ignored Tag leaking through the active tab (although today I also got a `Realm` tag suddenly appearing).

Maybe it's because it's a tag I often interact with, when retagging `parsing` to `parse.com` on questions in my active tab for example (I never interact with the other Ignored Tags).

UPDATE

One year later, I'm still experimenting the same issue with other tags, like this one:

[image]

Comment: I see this on meta too, especially when it says "X new questions" and I click it, it shows questions with my ignored tags, and I have to refresh to remove them. And that's on the default tab, not a custom tab...

Comment: I see this all the time.  For instance, I have `python*` as an ignored tag, but questions tagged `python`, `python-3.x`, etc are not being ignored. But I also have `*php*` ignored, and questions tagged `php`, `php-7`, etc are ignored correctly.  And ignoring `ruby*` ignores questions tagged `ruby-on-rails`, etc.  Something is definitely fishy about the ignore system.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this behavior too. The great thing is that there's a notification claiming that some results are hidden due to my ignored tag preferences. Oh, really?

[image]

Comment: Just curious; do you have [tag:javascript], [tag:mysql], [tag:ajax], or [tag:bootstrap-modal] in the list of tags for that tab? IOW, it might be including it for one of those tags, and just not removing it because of your ignored tag...